# Lightswitch HTML and sharepoint (Sideloading of apps is not enabled) error

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have recently purchased office 365, and thought id have a go at linking a lightswitch HTML 2015 project to it, and ive gotten as far as this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step: 'Install app for SharePoint':
>   Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site

I have been researching this for like an hour now and everything I have tried has failed... has any one else come accross this and can help me fix this issue, or at least point me in the right direction of things i can try to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't base the site on the developer template, you will need to activate the developer feature, see http://lekman.codeplex.com/releases/view/98505 for details on how to do so.

Comment: thankyou for the point in the right direction, the windows shell script did not work from that site for some reason, however I found one that did: http://lekman.codeplex.com/releases/view/98505       thanks for the info!

Comment: Glad you came right. I've adjusted the answer to use your link in case there's an error on the other link.

Answer (score 0):

We have to give developer site link here or we need to activate sideloading feature .

[image]